# How to load modal using HTML links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can load the modal using this piece of code with no issues.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="sweet_prompt">
    Deploy Code <i class="icon-play3 position-right"></i>
</button>
```

However, I need it as an HTML link and not a button (don't want to mess with the themes' CSS styling). Nothing happens when I click on the link.

```
<a href="#" data-target="#sweet_prompt" data-toggle="modal">
    <i class="icon-history position-left"></i>Deploy Code
</a>
```

Fixed: I modified it so that the link is constructed this way.

```
<a id="sweet_prompt">Deploy Code</a>
```

Comment: It should work, whether its a link or a button.

Comment: Almost certainly not the way this is written.

Comment: Seems to work out for me.. **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ch96x63x/)**

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? How is the modal being triggered?

Comment: Yes, there's a JS file included `<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/notifications/sweet_alert.min.js"></script>` in the head portion of the file. There is no modal code included in the file itself, it appears to be loading via a JS file.

Answer (score 0):

Given that we (currently) don't know how the modal is being triggered, I'll assume the listener is attached to either `button#sweet_prompt` or perhaps just `#sweet_prompt`.

Rewrite either the HTML of your link to use the selector the listener is attached to, or rewrite the listener to attach to the `<a/>` element.

Comment: Yeah I have no idea how the modal is being triggered. Here's the link to the template (search for "Prompt Dialog"). http://demo.interface.club/limitless/layout_4/LTR/components_modals.html

Answer (score 0):

Look this example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-target="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<div class="modal fade hide" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-remote="/mmfansler/aQ3Ge/show/">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is a template i purchased and there's no modal section in the HTML file. It looks like it's loading a JS file as such. `<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/notifications/sweet_alert.min.js"></script>`